# Error adding index with mapping to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to define mapping for elasticsearch but getting the following error (using KIBANA sense in localhost):

```
{
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
            "reason": "analyzer [whitespace_analyzer] not found for field [country]"
         }
      ],
      "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason": "Failed to parse mapping [package]: analyzer [whitespace_analyzer] not found for field [country]",
      "caused_by": {
         "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
         "reason": "analyzer [whitespace_analyzer] not found for field [country]"
      }
   },
   "status": 400
}
```

Mapping given :

```
PUT /worldV
{ 
"mappings" : {
  "package" : {
    "properties" : {
      "autosuggestionpackagedetail" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "index" : "not_analyzed"
      },
      "availability" : { 
          },
            ...... so on ....
```

Comment: The link times out, but I think if you change `whitespace_analyzer` to `whitespace` it should work

Comment: @Val I am getting error for nGram_analyzer now, tried nGram, ngram also {
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
            "reason": "analyzer [ngram] not found for field [country]"
         }
      ],
      "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason": "Failed to parse mapping [package]: analyzer [ngram] not found for field [country]",
      "caused_by": {
         "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
         "reason": "analyzer [ngram] not found for field [country]"
      }
   },
   "status": 400
}

Comment: You're missing all the `settings` (where analyzers are defined) in your index... make sure to setup your index correctly first

Comment: @Val If you check the URL I have mentioned, that URL also doesn't have setting defined but its working

Comment: As I said, that URL times out for me

Comment: @Val dude adding settings worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Of course it worked ;)